# Disallow multiple dynamic directory indexing is this working or not

Tags: robots.txt

ok im a bit confuse on this one been looking around could'nt find any answer so here i am.
im Looking to block multiple sub directory (dynamic url)

exemple:

```
/virtual-news/itemlist/allo/
/online-news/itemlist/hi/
/blahblah-news/itemlist/goodbye/
/something-news/itemlist/allllo/
```

so to block the spider from indexing any url containing /itemlist/ directory can I use this ?

```
Disallow: /*/itemlist/*
```

it would make sense ? but I am not sure and cant find much information on this

Comment: read this: `To exclude all files except one` [here](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html)

Comment: i just want to make sure i don't block all indexing to my site...

Comment: why you dont put a robots.txt in your *itemlist* folder with `User agent: * Disallow: /`?

Comment: i have read this http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html dosent help me much.. still no info on subdirectory.

Comment: there is no itemlist directory its a dynamic URL.

Answer (score 0):

If the bots have not indexed content from your site yet, then blocking access from `robots.txt` is fine. If they have already indexed content and you want it removed, then don't block access and return a 404 or a 410 instead (from https://youtu.be/G29Zt-UH_Ko).